# Truffle compiles and migrates the wrong contract

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

I have an initial folder with an extension of the tutorial, and I'm now working in a new folder:

```
new-project
 |
 +- build
 +- contracts
 |         +- NewContract.sol
 |
 +- migrations
 +- ...

truffle-test
 |
 +-pet-shop-tutorial
 +-old-project
 |         +- build
 |         +- contracts
 |                   +- oldContract.sol
```

I made the `new_project` as a copy of `old-project`, but now when I'm in the `new-project` folder and I run `truffle compile` or `truffle migrate` what I see is:

```
Compiling .\..\truffle-test\old-project\contracts\OldContract.sol...
Writing artifacts to .\build\contracts
[...]
```

And truffle actually writes the artifacts of the old contract in the new folder!

I'm left with this:

```
new-project
 |
 +- build
 |         +- OldContract.JSON
 |         +- NewContract.JSON
 +- contracts
 |         +- NewContract.sol
```

And the new contract doesn't seem to be deployed. I edited `1_initial_migration.js` to mention the new contract, and it's still not deployed.

What should I do? Did I forget something? How do I prevent truffle from compiling from other folders?

Comment: never experienced this issue but you might try to initialize your folder using `truffle init`. If you need some contracts or file from the old project just copy it

Comment: Have you tried focussing on the new map when migrating for instance? `truffle migrate ./folder/file`

Comment: try deleting your build folder, then rerunning 'truffle migrate'.  Also make sure that you changed the name of your contract in the solidity file (Contract name matches file name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As thefett suggested, it worked to delete the build folder.

My guess is that the Migration contract was already built but with wrong information, and because the JSON existed `truffle compile` didn't replace it.

When the folder was cleared, the compilation build the correct JSONs and the deployment went as expected.